# Bubbling events from child to parent (overal progress)

Tags: c#, events

I have a problem which i don't know how to solve.
I have some classes (Processors) that fires an event with progress information ( Percentage of how far it is). There are multiple processors that do this and the top Processor (Engine) which calls them all needs to send information to the end user on its progress. 
If i don't know beforehand how many items will be processed by each processor how can i give the user some good feedback on how far the process is?

Take a look at the following simplified example

[NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/StWFWK)

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    var p = new Program();
    p.Run();
  }

  private void Run() {
    var engine = new Engine();
    engine.UpdateProgress += Engine_UpdateProgress;
    engine.Process();


    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  private void Engine_UpdateProgress(object sender, UpdateProgressEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{e.UpdateDateTime} - Caller: {e.Caller}, Percentage: {e.Percentage}");
  }
}

public class Engine {
  private readonly ProcessorA _processorA;
  private readonly ProcessorB _processorB;
  private readonly ProcessorC _processorC;
  private readonly ProcessorD _processorD;

  public event EventHandler<UpdateProgressEventArgs> UpdateProgress;

  public Engine() {
    _processorA = new ProcessorA();
    _processorB = new ProcessorB();
    _processorC = new ProcessorC();
    _processorD = new ProcessorD();

    //Handle events
    _processorA.UpdateProgress += ProcessorA_UpdateProgress;
    _processorB.UpdateProgress += ProcessorA_UpdateProgress;
    _processorC.UpdateProgress += ProcessorA_UpdateProgress;
    _processorD.UpdateProgress += ProcessorA_UpdateProgress;
  }

  private void ProcessorA_UpdateProgress(object sender, UpdateProgressEventArgs e) {
    OnUpdateProgress(e);
  }

  public void Process() {
    _processorA.Process();
    _processorB.Process();
    _processorC.Process();
    _processorD.Process();
  }

  protected virtual void OnUpdateProgress(UpdateProgressEventArgs e) {
    UpdateProgress?.Invoke(this, e);
  }
}

public class ProcessorA : Processor {
  private readonly ProcessorA_A _processorA_A;

  public ProcessorA() {
    _processorA_A = new ProcessorA_A();

    //Handle events
    _processorA_A.UpdateProgress += ProcessorA_A_UpdateProgress;
  }

  public void Process() {
    _processorA_A.Process();
  }

  private void ProcessorA_A_UpdateProgress(object sender, UpdateProgressEventArgs e) {
    OnUpdateProgress(e);
  }
}

public class ProcessorB : Processor {
  public void Process() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      var args = new UpdateProgressEventArgs() { Caller = nameof(ProcessorB), Percentage = i, UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now};
      //Do some work
      Thread.Sleep(r.Next(50,250));
      OnUpdateProgress(args);
    }
  }
}

public class ProcessorC : Processor {
  public void Process() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      var args = new UpdateProgressEventArgs() { Caller = nameof(ProcessorC), Percentage = i, UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now };
      //Do some work
      Thread.Sleep(r.Next(50, 250));
      OnUpdateProgress(args);
    }
  }
}

public class ProcessorD : Processor {
  public void Process() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      var args = new UpdateProgressEventArgs() { Caller = nameof(ProcessorD), Percentage = i, UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now };
      //Do some work
      Thread.Sleep(r.Next(50, 250));
      OnUpdateProgress(args);
    }
  }
}

public class ProcessorA_A : Processor {
  public void Process() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      var args = new UpdateProgressEventArgs() { Caller = nameof(ProcessorA_A), Percentage = i, UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now };
      //Do some work
      Thread.Sleep(r.Next(50, 250));
      OnUpdateProgress(args);
    }
  }
}

public class Processor : IProcessor {
  protected Random r = new Random();
  public event EventHandler<UpdateProgressEventArgs> UpdateProgress;

  protected virtual void OnUpdateProgress(UpdateProgressEventArgs e) {
    UpdateProgress?.Invoke(this, e);
  }
}

public interface IProcessor {
  event EventHandler<UpdateProgressEventArgs> UpdateProgress;
}

public class UpdateProgressEventArgs {
  public int Percentage { get; set; }
  public string Caller { get; set; }
  public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Just sending the progress from child to parent won't do the trick obviously. I hope someone can help me find a solution for this. Or if someone has another brilliant solution :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't know what and how many you should do, you can give an update how far you are. Why does a processor doesn't know how many things it should do?

Comment: Depends on how fine grained you want it. Engine knows how man Processors it has. And it _could_ know how many of them have a progress of 100% or lower. So your Engine-Progress could simply be # of Processors @ 100% ... or added %ages / # of Processors.

Comment: you need to add handles to all of the children events, so you do actually know how many processors are running, so you have 100 * (number of processes) for your grand total completeness. The "grand total completeness" should be what the parent reports to whatever's listening to that? is this not what you want?

Comment: If a processor should process a queue (where items could be pushed on), you should return the `items needs to be process` instead of a `percentage`.

Comment: @Jordy van Eijk, You've got 3 answers to your question, Please either reply to them explaining why they are not suitable answers or pick an accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Engine could maintain a private list of "the last completeness" of each process. In a Dictionary more than likely.

if we extend your `Engine` class to have this.

```
private Dictionary<IProcessor, int> _lastReportedPercentage = new Dictionary<IProcessor, int>();
```

and in the constructor where all your child processors are defined, set them all to 0.

```
public Engine()
{
    //your other stuff
    _lastReportedPercentage[_processorA] = 0;
    _lastReportedPercentage[_processorB] = 0;
    _lastReportedPercentage[_processorC] = 0;
    _lastReportedPercentage[_processorD] = 0;
}
```

in your Event handler for the child processes do something like this:

```
private void ProcessorA_UpdateProgress(object sender, UpdateProgressEventArgs e)
{
    _lastReportedPercentage[(IProcessor)sender] = e.Percentage;
    var totalCompleteness = (int)Math.Floor(_lastReportedPercentage.Values.Sum() / _lastReportedPercentages.Values.Count);
    OnUpdateProgress(new UpdateProgressEventArgs() { Caller = nameof(Engine), Percentage = totalCompleteness, UpdateDateTime = DateTime.Now });
}
```

You will then be reporting, from your Engine, the total completeness of all tasks.

There are some obvious design flaws to this, but you get the idea. It can be extended for a variable number of Processors if they're loaded from not-the-constructor, etc. but this should give you the desired output you'd want.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This worked out for me. Although i have to make some adjustments but this is a nice solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having each processor keep a count of how many items it has completed, and how many items it has remaining.

This way the engine receives updates whenever an item is completed, as well as when an item is added to the processor.

As in Skintkingle's answer, you would then store the last received update from each processor within the engine.

You can then let the engine decide on the best way to put this information across. Something as simple as total completed / total remaining would work well.